# Form Validation for multiple Models with same column names

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

Identical column names from two tables are conflicting in validation process.

Simplified Tables and Models:

there is a column 'name' on table *users*

```
class User extends Model {

     protected $fillable = ['name'];

     public static function rules() {
        return [
            'name'     => 'required|unique:users',
        ];
     }
}
```

there is a column 'name' on table *siblings*

```
class Sibling extends Model {

     protected $fillable = ['name'];

     public static function rules() {
        return [
            'name'     => 'required',
        ];
     }
}
```

Part of Form from View:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="name">User Name</label>
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"/>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="name">Sibling Name</label>
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Stripped Controller function:

```
public function store(Request $request){
   $userValidation = $this->validate($request, User::rules());
   $siblingValidation = $this->validate($request, Sibling::rules());

   $user = new User();
   $user->create($request);

   $sibling = new Sibling;
   $sibling->create($request);
}
```

---

Obviously changing the database column names to not be the same would work.

My Question:

1. What are the common approaches to this problem?
2. How do I change the controller or form name attributes to eliminate this problem.

Side note:
I don't use laravelcollective/html, so an answer without it would be preferable, but if it does considerably simplify the solution process then I might consider it.

**Update:**
Is there a way using eager loading or similar to save the POST elements directly without reassigning them? I'm imaging something such as setting the field names to `name="user.name"` and `name="sibling.name"`, which laravel would automatically recognise.

Answer (score 0):

I would just change the key in the rules array.

```
//User Model
return [
        'user_name'     => 'required|unique:users',
    ]

//Sibling Model
return [
        'sibling_name'     => 'required',
    ];
```

And in my HTML

```
<!-- User Name -->
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name"/>

<!-- Sibling Name -->
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sibling_name"/>
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

You won't need to change the column names in the DB.

Here is how you can save the models.

```
// Method to create User and Sibling   

// Create User.
$user = new User;
$user->name = $request->user_name;
$user->save();

//Create Sibling.
$sibling = new Sibling;
$sibling->name = $request->sibling_name;
// Associate User with Sibling
$sibling->save();
```

Comment: This means that I will have to change the database column names accordingly, right? or does Laravel recognise it automatically if it is in that pattern?  `$user->save()`

Comment: No, you don't need to change the column names. Laravel validation happens on the `name` attribute of the form, not on the column name. Updated the answer to show how you would save these values.

Comment: I see, so its just plain php, where I have to reassign. There is no way for eager loading or such that will save me the reassignment coding in this case.  So the following won't be possible:
`$user->save($request)  
$sibling->save($request)`

Thank you. 
I  will try and update my question aswell.